# Moment.js returning wrong date (one year ahead)

Tags: node.js, date, momentjs

I was running some tests and got a problem on Moment.js

The date on my database is `2001-06-06T00:00:00.000+00:00`.

I used  `Age: moment(user.dateOfBirth).toNow(true)` and I got `"Age": "21 years"` when it clearly should be `20`.

The `dateOfBirth` propriety is set as Date on my schema. I filled it as `2001-06-06`.

I also tried using .diff and I got a random number. Is the issue on the date's formatting?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

toNow is giving approximate value, it is rounding off.
What you can use is duration.

```js
const dateOfBirth = "2001-06-06";
const age1 = moment("2001-06-06", "yyyy-mm-dd").toNow(true);

const age2 = moment.duration(moment().diff(moment(dateOfBirth)))._data["years"];

console.log(age1);
console.log(age2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: [Still says 21 years in Firefox](https://i.imgur.com/DNFeiqT.png) and [same in Chrome](https://i.imgur.com/krOJD1o.png) - where do you see it work?

Comment: I made some mistake, updated my answer.